# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am making a small test web store in Laravel. Tried to edit user profile. There are so many fields:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('img')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

But I'm trying to change only 3 of them, and an error is displayed that others do not have a default value, and why does it even touch other fields? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
public function user_edit(Request $request, User $user){

      $user->name = $request->name?$request->name:Auth::user()->name;
      $user->email = $request->email?$request->email:Auth::user()->email;
      $user->phone = $request->phone?$request->phone:(Auth::user()->phone?Auth::user()->phone:NULL);
      $user->save();

      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use :

```
$user->update();
```

`$user->save();` will perform an `INSERT`

**EDIT**

The error is maybe because your `$user` in params is not defined or not found.

So instead of updating your User instance when you use `->save()`, it tries to create a new one.

You can't inject the authentificated User like this, as mentionned, you can use :

```
  $user = auth()->user();
  $user->name = $request->name?$request->name:$user->name;
  $user->email = $request->email?$request->email : $user->email;
  $user->phone = $request->phone?$request->phone : ($user->phone?$user->phone:NULL);
  $user->save();
```

Not the best honestly but can explain the error.

Comment: `update()` is `fill([])->save()` ... calls the same `save` method

Comment: @lagbox you are right, so it will mean the $user is not correctly set, but the update shouldn't work neither.

Comment: exactly, it would have just not done anything as it was an non-existing instance of the model do to dependency injection ... they switched to using the auth user

Answer (score 1):

Also, I have not specified `user_id` anywhere. So, at the top I added:

`$user=Auth::user();`

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function user_edit(Request $request, User $user){

  $user->name = $request->name?$request->name:Auth::user()->name;
  $user->email = $request->email?$request->email:Auth::user()->email;
  $user->phone = $request->phone?$request->phone:(Auth::user()->phone?Auth::user()->phone:NULL);
  $user->password = $request->password?$request->password:Auth::user()->password;
  $user->save();

  return redirect()->back();
}
```